# how to create abstract state value on react

Tags: reactjs, state, abstract

I want to have an abstract default state value in react on a mapped component. logic goes like this
1. json of parameters
2. mapped json parameters to objects
3. set default value of objects depending on item.value

no idea how to do number 3

Here's the code,

```
    function parameterItem(item) {
        if(item.type === 'date') {
            return <Input type="date" name={ item.name } defaultValue={this.state.[item.value]} id={ item.name} form="form-filter" />
        }
    }

    if(this.props.filter) {
        parameters = this.props.filter.map((item, id) => {
            if (Object.keys(item).length > 0) {
                return <Col xs='12' key={id} hidden={ !item.visible }>
                    <Row className="form-spacing-top">
                        <Col xs='3'>
                            <p>{ item.caption }</p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs='9'>
                            { parameterItem(item) }
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            } else return null
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean depending on item.value or item.type ?

Comment: depending on item.value set from parameter.json

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say that you have a mapping like this somewhere in some file:

**mapping_constants.js:**

```
default_value_mappings = {
    "value1": "Some Value1", 
    ...
    ...
    "valueN":"Some Value N"
}
```

Which can be mapped as:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({"defaults":default_value_mappings})

}
function parameterItem(item) {
    if(item.type === 'date') {
            return <Input type="date" name={ item.name } defaultValue={this.state.defaults[item.value]} id={ item.name} form="form-filter" />
    }
}
```

Did I get the question correct?

Comment: So did I answer your query of you are still looking for some other mechanism?

Comment: I changed the state into a variable, then assigned the variable as the item.name as

function parameterItem(item) {
 if(item.type === 'date') {
  return <Input type="date" name={ item.name } id={ item.name} defaultValue={[item.name]} form="form-filter" />
 }
}

I got it however. I cannot get the value of the [item.name] instead only gets a string value of the name only